# How to center a table with respect to the page, and how to reduce its font size?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I need a table to be centered with respect to the page. By default it is aligned with the left text border, and being large it exceeds the right page margin:

[image]

This is the Org-mode source:

```
Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text,
Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text,
Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text,

#+ATTR_LATEX: :center
| ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ |
|----------------------------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
| ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ |
| ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ |
| ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ |
```

I tried adding this before my table:

```
#+BEGIN_LaTeX
  \hspace{-5cm}
#+END_LaTeX
```

but it had no effect on the table alignment, it only printed the "LaTeX" string.

As an alternative, how can I reduce the font size for the table contents? This, placed before the table, had no effect:

```
#+begin_export html
<style>
.reveal  td {font-size: 60%;}
</style>
#+end_export
```

I am interested in both the HTML(5) and PDF exports.

The commands I am using are:

```
$ emacs file.org --batch -f org-latex-export-to-pdf --kill
$ emacs file.org --batch -f org-html-export-to-html --kill
```

Comment: For the alignment, see [Table export in LaTeX](https://orgmode.org/manual/Tables-in-LaTeX-export.html). For CSS, see [CSS support](https://orgmode.org/manual/CSS-support.html).

Comment: BTW, when I export a table to PDF, it is centered by default - so I'm not sure what you are seeing.

Comment: Also, one question per question please: depending on how you count here, there are either two or four questions. At the very least, you should ask the two questions in your title in separate questions.

Comment: @NickD - I added the LaTeX `:center` attribute, which has no effect. See the output I added to my question.

Comment: @NickD - The question is a single one, i.e. make the table contents fit in the page, and the reduced font size would be an alternative approach.

Comment: OK, I missed the "large table" comment, so I was confusedd about the centering part, and given that, it certainly wasn't clear that the font reductions was supposed to be an alternative solution. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: There is still the question about LaTeX/PDF on one side and HTML on the other. It's not clear to me what the HTML problem is, partly because there is no "page" concept in HTML (HTML pages are whole documents, nothing like the pages of a book which is what LaTeX/PDF simulates). In particular, your example renders fine for me in HTML.

Comment: The HTML output is the same as the PDF one, with the addition of a slider which allows to scroll and see all the table contents. Here the issue is that the whole text and the table only occupy a narrow column at the center of the web page, leaving tow wide blank margins on both sides.

Comment: That's a different problem, best asked in a different question (although you can refer back to this one for context). Providing a test input file and the screenshot of the results as you did above should go a long way towards eliciting a quick answer from somebody well-versed in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are mostly LaTeX problems, not Org mode problems. Org mode
knows a tiny bit about LaTeX, so the way to solve the problem is to
solve it in LaTeX first and then retrofit the Org mode file to export
to the desired LaTeX. In general, the [TeX SE site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)  is the proper
place for them, but you have to talk about LaTeX there: Org mode is
not what they know.

Here are some links to related questions from that site:

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255727/centering-a-wide-table
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39435/how-can-i-center-a-too-wide-table - this is pretty much your question.

I'm sure there are others.

---

### LaTeX/PDF

Here are a couple of methods, based mostly on the above links, to
deal with the problems on the Org mode side. But note that I went
backwards: once I knew how to do something in LaTeX, I
reverse-engineered the solution back to Org mode.

First, the above link shows a method to have the wide table hang into
both margins:

```tex
\makebox[\textwidth][c]{<table>}
```

where `<table>` is a placeholder for the whole LaTeX table. I tested
this by having the Org mode exporter produce a `.tex` file (`C-c C-e l l`) and then playing around with that file. I added
`\makebox[\textwidth][c]{` before the LaTeX table and I closed it with
`}` after the table and processed the file through `xelatex`. The
result is that the table is shifted over and starts at the left edge of
the page, sticking out into the left margin. However, it is too wide
even with that and sticks out into the right margin and to the right
edge of the page - and it still doesn't fit: the last `XYZ` on every
row is cut off. It is also very ugly of course.

Nevertheless, I retrofitted it to your Org mode example, and I added two
more tables to show the differences: one table with reduced font and one
with both methods applied at the same time:

```org
* Test

Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text,
Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text,
Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text, Normal text,

#+LATEX: \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
#+ATTR_LATEX: :center nil
| ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ |
|----------------------------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
| abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz |
| abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz |
| abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz |
#+LATEX: }

#+LATEX: {\tiny
| ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ |
|----------------------------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
| abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz |
| abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz |
| abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz |
#+LATEX: }


#+LATEX: {\tiny \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
#+ATTR_LATEX: :center nil
| ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ | ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ |
|----------------------------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
| abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz |
| abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz |
| abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz | abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz |
#+LATEX: }}
```

The [`#+LATEX` keyword
lines](https://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-LaTeX-code.html) add the
rest of the line literally to the `.tex` file at that point, so after
the exporter processes the table into LaTeX, the table is surrounded
by the `\makebox` construct (or the `{\tiny` construct in the second
table or both in the third table), exactly as specified in the linked
question. The centering is done through the `[c]` argument of the
`\makebox` macro here.

N.B. in the `\makebox` cases, I had to turn off the default centering
of the table that the LaTeX exporter does by using `#+ATTR_LATEX: :center nil`: otherwise, I get errors.

### HTML

I don't think there is a similar problem with HTML: "pages" in HTML
are really whole documents, not like the pages of a book which
LaTeX/PDF try to emulate. They are elastic in that (in the absence of
other constraints), they will accommodate content as wide as the
window (which can be resized) and even wider, by providing scrollbars
to allow you to view the off-screen part of the content.

In fact, processing your example through the HTML exporter works fine for me.

[The OP added a comment, describing the problem that he sees with HTML export, but I believe that's a different problem, best dealt with in a different questions.]

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thank you!